# How to manage files locally in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: file, directory

I am pretty new to Visual Studio, so sorry for this stupid question.

I have no idea how to manage my files locally. All I can find is some Github or TFS support. So where is this view for managing files and foldes in VS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View > Solution Explorer.  The files should open up on the right or the left if you have your solution open already.  If you do not have it open just do a File > Open

The solution explorer will allow you to see all the files to edit delete and add.